# Creating a fillable PDF form with ITextSharp

Tags: forms, pdf, itext, field

I have created a PDF file using Acrobat Adobe 8 that contains fillable fields.

Can that be programmed with ITextSharp instead of Adobe?

Note: I am not referring to filling out the PDF with ITextSharp, instead I would like to *create* the fillable fields on the PDF file using ITextSharp.

Any code would be appreciated.

thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create PDFs that contain fillable fields with iText[Sharp], but they won't look as nice as Adobe Acrobat, which is a much better *design* tool.

By fillable fields, I'm guessing you mean a [TextField](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/TextField.html). Here's a [link with some simple example code](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter08&ex=TextFields) from [the book](http://itextpdf.com/book/) to get you started. Specifically, take a look at the `CreatePdf()` and `CellLayout()` methods, and the [iText API](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/) if you need more information.

Comment: After reading the API, PdfFormField.CreateTextField is what was required.

Comment: Yes, that's a **different** way to create a text field. As stated, the example code referenced in the answer was written to **explicitly demonstrate** how to create PDF text fields with iText[Sharp] by the **creator** of iText.