# Creating PDF from HTML using iTextSharp with TextField and editing the same later

Tags: itext

I have a requirement to create a PDF file from HTML.  The resulting PDF needs to have iTextSharp TextField or something similar.  I need to update the PDF document with appropriate text in the text field.

Points to note:

```
1. The PDF length (page numbers) may vary.
2. Due to this, I may have to only know the name of the field to set value to.
```

OR

I could create a PDF from HTML.  As the content of the PDF may vary, I do not know the exact location of a block that I need to edit.  I need to stamp text exactly over the block irrespective of the location of the block (i.e. the block may exist in any page).

Example Scenario:

1. Create a PDF from HTML.
2. It is sent for approval process.  Once it is approved, the name of the approver is printed at a specific place (however the signature area, mentioned as block above, may come at any page, as it depends on the content of the HTML).

Answer (score 0):

Two resources which may help you:

This article details how to use asp.net & itextsharp to create a pdf.
The whole article is pretty useful for a beginner like me, but the section detailing how to create a pdf from HTML may be useful for you as a start on your problem.
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001758/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030911-1.aspx
I would especially pay attention to how he replaces placeholders in the HTML template he is loading. As it seems you may want to head in that direction.

Now to answer your question more directly, have you thought about using a fillable form?
Here is a related Stack Overflow post.
[Creating a fillable PDF form with ITextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350186/creating-a-fillable-pdf-form-with-itextsharp)

As I said I am a beginner, so I can't do much to help you from here. But with any luck you can put those together and accomplish what you are looking for.

Let me know if that helps Good luck!