# How to create an editable pdf in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext, abcpdf

here is a different type of requirement in my project regarding pdf.

I want to generate a pdf with few of prefilled values. rest of the fields can be filled by user so Pdf should allow the user to edit the pdf so that he can save it locally on his system.

The pdf may contain checkboxes and textboxes.

I have worked with "itextsharp", "abc pdf" and "Rad Pdf".

For this purpose i can't use "Rad Pdf", due to some limitations by project owner. 
Please share your valuable answers to give me a proper way to do this task.

Looking forward for your replies.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055838/commercial-html-to-pdf-component-for-net

Comment: similar question sovled [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350186/creating-a-fillable-pdf-form-with-itextsharp)

Comment: @Win how can i find out that which one will work for me?

Comment: @Nil Its a fillable pdf not an editable pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Adobe Professional, you can turn your existing electronic or paper forms into fillable forms with a few clicks.

http://adobe.ly/Ydc7qb

Comment: Can you give me few more details. Please elaborate, how to do this?

Comment: @Code Rider: 1. buy Adobe Professional.  2. Read the instructions on creating a PDF Form.  3. ???? 4. Profit.  As an alternative, try http://www.pdfescape.com/  It's pretty good and free.

Comment: @ChrisLively ohhh, you are going wrong. when user download the pdf from my site. He shouldn't need these kind of products to edit the pdf. Can't he do without using such kind of products?

Comment: The client doesn't need the professional version; you need it to create the fillable form :/

Comment: @CodeRider You should make clear which PDF viewer you expect the users to have. IrishChieftain assumes you expect them to use Acrobat Reader. In that case, pdfs have to be "Reader enabled" which is only possible using Adobe software.

Comment: I have posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418940/pdfs-fields-should-remain-editable-using-itextsharp-in-asp-net), please check this one. This may elaborate, what i exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat Reader XI provides features to save eForms out of the box.

Provided your clients are using this version of Acrobat they will be able to fill in and save standard PDF forms.

The only problem you may have relates to older versions of Acrobat Reader which did not have this feature.

So any eForm produced using ABCpdf or indeed any PDF library should work the way you want provided your clients have a recent version of Acrobat Reader.

ABCpdf includes an example project called 'Annotations' which shows how to create eForms in this way.

My replies may feature concepts based around ABCpdf .NET because it's something I work on. :-)