# On demand sub reports in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report where I am using an on-demand sub-report.  But my user is viewing this report from a java application.  So whenever he run the report he will view this report in PDF.

Report format:

```
country name         location            sales

<on-demand subreport>
```

Now once he run the report he will get all the above fields data in PDF format.

So now if clicked on location field data in PDF will he get the sub-report's data.

Comment: To the extent I know...no he won't get the data in pdf

Comment: Hi Siva is there any way to get this by using hyperlinks something.I am using on demand sub reports for this.

Comment: The PDF format doesn't support the feature that you want to implement.

Comment: Sorry to say but I dont have idea on hyperlinks

Comment: Hi Craig the approach I am using for this is ondemand sub report method.Can we use other approach like hyperlink to call other report.If possible please suggest how to do.

Comment: Are you using BusinessObjects Enterprise or Crystal Reports Server?

Comment: I once tried setting up something similar where essentially links would be generated in the PDF that would take you to another PDF or another part of the current PDF which would act as opening the subreport. I gave up...the complexity of doing that is not at all worth it. If you are not dissuaded, you might find some use in using [VisualCUT](http://www.milletsoftware.com/Visual_CUT.htm)

Comment: Hi Craig not using both.I am using cr 2011 and I am deploying my reports in java portal

Answer (score 0):

PDF isn't intended to generate dynamic content.  As such, you'll need to find an approach that will render the desire content in a static manner.

I would suggest that you parameterize your report to display one of these options:

1. main only
2. main + subreport

The PDF will either contain the main report's content or the main and subreport's content.

** edit **
If you are using BusinessObjects Enterprise (BOE), you could use the openDocument API to generate a new report instance or the most-recently-generated instance.  I don't know if Crystal Reports Server supports this feature for certain.

If you are rendering reports in a Java application, then you will need to a way to intercept the hyperlinks--a server, most likely.  By in large, you'd be reinventing Crystal Reports Server/BOE.

Comment: Hi Craig,But my requirement is I have a report where it is showing all the locations.If I clicked on particular location it will show that particular location details which is coming from  another report.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I understand as you need two thing.

1. you need to generate a report and export/generate in pdf.
2. in you need to attach link or something like editable field pdf.

For First answer, you can easily hide/show of sub-report in crystal report side. but not after report generate in pdf.

So for second answer, you need to pdf professional or editable allow version. after you get that you simply use itextsharp.dll (to generate pdf from asp.net-see below link).

So finally I think, does not needed crystal report.

please check this link.
[How to create an editable pdf in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411251/how-to-create-an-editable-pdf-in-asp-net)

[Pdf's fields should remain editable using itextsharp in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418940/pdfs-fields-should-remain-editable-using-itextsharp-in-asp-net)

[Creating a fillable PDF form with ITextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350186/creating-a-fillable-pdf-form-with-itextsharp)